# Interpreting a Registry value of hashed password

Tags: passwords, hash, forensics, registry

I have been given a forensics challenge that contains a SYSTEM and SAM registry files as well as a wordlist.

When using `hivexsh` (a registry analysis tool) I need to find the password (which I belive to be hashed with  the NTLM in the `SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000003EB>` which is the corresponding password for the user) which when using the `lsval` command in hivexsh I get the following:

```
"F"=hex(3):02,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,f9,3e,7e,cd,67,4e,d4,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,63,88,bc,3d,85,84,d3,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,eb,03,00,00,01,02,00,00,10,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,08,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"V"=hex(3):00,00,00,00,bc,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,bc,00,00,00,16,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,d4,00,00,00,26,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fc,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,08,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,48,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,4c,01,00,00,14,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,60,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,64,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,9c,00,00,00,ac,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,44,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,58,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,24,00,44,00,02,00,01,05,00,00,00,00,00,05,15,00,00,00,48,d8,35,b5,07,d0,c1,b7,a3,11,76,5e,eb,03,00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,14,00,5b,03,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,73,00,73,00,68,00,64,00,5f,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,00,00,73,00,73,00,68,00,64,00,20,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,20,00,61,00,63,00,63,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,00,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,53,00,53,00,48,00,5c,00,76,00,61,00,72,00,5c,00,65,00,6d,00,70,00,74,00,79,00,01,02,00,00,07,00,00,00,03,00,01,00,03,00,01,00,03,3a,5d,b4,8c,3b,4d,05,ab,97,4d,1c,d5,10,eb,e9,03,00,01,00,03,00,01,00
```

Could someone tell me how/or what form the hash would be from the above so I can continue the challenge?

Comment: The point of the challenge is for you to find the solution yourself.

Comment: I understand but I’ve spent hours researching but I can’t find anything explaining even the form on the hivexsh value.

Comment: Offensive Security has [pretty good advice for that](https://www.offensive-security.com/offsec/say-try-harder/).

Comment: it looks like a very poor hash, unless that's not actually their password.

Comment: Are you guys not giving any help because you don't know how to give help. I asked a question, which I could find any information on elsewhere. If you cannot answer the question - please refrain from giving useless comments.

Comment: @Jasen I don't mind if its a poor hash or not, I just would like to know the form the hash would be in. Thanks, any help would be appricated. :)

Comment: I have given all the help I can, hashes typically have higher entropy, those fields are mostly zeroes.

Comment: with so many zeroes it could be a Bloom hash of some sort, or you could just have extreme luck.

Comment: Well I know (Because of the form V = etc) it is NTLM hash. But thanks for the help!